# Cross Compiling GLib for MIPS results in "No iconv() implementation" configure error

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, configure, glib

I'm trying to cross-compile GLib 2.37.0 for a MIPS system by following the directions [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-cross-compiling.html).  I have a mips.cache file with the following contents:

```
glib_cv_stack_grows=no
glib_cv_uscore=no
ac_cv_func_posix_getpwuid_r=no
ac_cv_func_posix_getgrgid_r=no
```

I'm calling the configure script with the following command line:

```
./configure --cache-file=mips.cache --host=mips-linux CCFLAGS=-I/opt/toolchain/build_mips/staging_dir/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/toolchain/build_mips/staging_dir/usr/lib
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
configure: error: *** No iconv() implementation found in C library or libiconv
```

If it helps, the entire output is:

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for mips-linux-gcc... mips-linux-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether mips-linux-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for mips-linux-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of mips-linux-gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... mips-linux-gcc -E
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... mips-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for the BeOS... no
checking for Win32... no
checking for the Android... no
checking for Mac OS X Carbon support... no
checking for Mac OS X Cocoa support... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2.1 or newer... yes
checking whether to enable garbage collector friendliness... no
checking whether to disable memory pools... no
checking for mips-linux-c++... mips-linux-c++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether mips-linux-c++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of mips-linux-c++... gcc3
checking whether mips-linux-gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking for mips-linux-pkg-config... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for perl5... no
checking for perl... perl
checking for indent... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.5... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for iconv_open... no
configure: error: *** No iconv() implementation found in C library or libiconv
```

I've tried calling the configure script with the `--with-libiconv=no` option, but the result is the same.  I know from other sources that the mips.cache file is good, but I don't know the magic for getting the configure script to work.  I have also used this toolchain to cross-compile other applications.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because libiconv will no be built with correct compiler(ie compiler for mips in this case) or the library(.so) will not be there in the path specified while configuring glib.

Comment: Does that mean I should cross-compile libiconv and then cross-compile GLib?

Comment: Did you resolve this because I am also trying to cross compile glib2.0 for MIPS architecture?